# Pwa. On deferredPrompt.prompt() DOMException

Tags: progressive-web-apps, domexception

While trying to install a PWA with this code:

```
 btnAddPwa.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        deferredPrompt.prompt();
 })
```

Is throwing a error message

[image]

[image]

This is still a problem. Anyone have idea of how to solve this?

Comment: What are the details of the `DOMException`, message, stacktrace and all that?

Comment: Could you click the `>` next to `[[PromiseValue]]`? It should show you the fields of the exception.

Comment: Yes... I´ve found it... it goes like this->
code: 0
message: "The prompt() method must be called with a user gesture"
name: "NotAllowedError"
But is being called when the user clicks the button

Comment: Now just stopped throwing the exception. What´s going on? Actually comes and goes. It´s not stable

Comment: Sometimes it works. And sometimes throws this exception. No obvious reason

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example we can have a look at?

Comment: @Caramiriel... What you mean by reproducible example? How could I do that?